# degree of finite extension of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Given a field extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$,  I'm trying to prove that $[\mathbb{F}_{p^m}:\mathbb{F}_p]=m$.
Important note: I'm trying to prove it without using the fact that $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^m}/\mathbb{F}_p)$ is cyclic group of order $m$.

Comment: A vector space of dimension $d$ over $\Bbb F_p$ has $p^d$ elements.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but is this necessarily implies the other direction? that is: A vector space with $p^d$ elements over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is with dimension $d$. This is the relevant direction

Comment: @TNT6 If you take for granted that a vector space has basis and well-defined dimension (independent on the basis), then a space of dimension $k$ has $p^k$ elements

Comment: @PeterFranek Maybe I'm missing something, but this is still the wrong direction. I want to prove that the dimension is $k$, so I cannot assume it and than show that the vector space has $p^k$ elements

Comment: If you believe that each vector space has a well-defined dimension $k$ for some $k$, then $p^k=p^d$ implies $k=d$